# How can I render a form with form.io using vanilla JS?

Tags: formio

I am playing with the form.io [demo on CodePen](http://codepen.io/travist/full/xVyMjo/), but it uses Angular. Assuming I have a basic JSON form and an html page not tied to any framework, what is the simplest way to render the form, initializing the form with an optional model, and collecting the model once the form is submitted?

Is there a form.io JavaScript library that does such a thing?

Example form.io JSON form snippet:

```
{
  components: [
  {
    input: true,
    tableView: true,
    inputType: "text",
    inputMask: "",
    label: "First Name",
    key: "firstName",
```

Answer (score 1):

The formio developers provide [formio.js](https://github.com/formio/formio.js) for this specific use case. Here is the link

Comment: I looked at the code and that script loads forms from the server and exposes CRUD operations. I was hoping they had a library to actually render forms. They have a cool product, but I don't see a way to reuse their client-side functionality.

Comment: This library renders the forms. See the examples found here https://formio.github.io/formio.js/

Answer (score 0):

as per their own documentation:
in your index:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./node_modules/formiojs/dist/formio.form.min.css" />
<script src="node_modules/formiojs/dist/formio.form.min.js"></script>
<div id="formID" class="demo-box">Loading...</div>
```

then in your js:

```
let schema = {
  components: [
  {
    input: true,
    tableView: true,
    inputType: "text",
    inputMask: "",
    label: "First Name",
    key: "firstName"
  }]
}
let data = {}
let formio = new Formio.createForm(document.getElementById('formID'), schema, data)
```

i recommend using this site to build your schema: https://formio.github.io/formio.js/app/sandbox